# Handle tS3Connection failure in Talend

Tags: amazon-s3, talend

I'm using the `tS3Connection` component and when I give it an invalid Access Key the console is showing a `403` error coming back from Amazon, but Talend is not catching that error if I connect the the component to a `tDie` component via `OnSubJobError`.

[image]

The rest of the job continues to proceed as if nothing is wrong which is not OK. Is there a way for me to catch this error and die gracefully?

Also if I try to read the `ERROR MESSAGE` attribute from the `tS3Connection` component, it always returns a `null`.

Comment: Are you using connection created by tS3Connection component in another component?

Comment: I'm using the connection to run a Get from an S3 bucket.